# Timescale/Postgres queries very slow/inefficient?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have table in TimescaleDb with the following schema:

```
create table market_quotes
(
    instrument     varchar(16) not null,
    exchange       varchar(16) not null,
    time           timestamp   not null,
    bid_1_price    double precision,
    ask_1_price    double precision,
    bid_1_quantity double precision,
    ask_1_quantity double precision,
    bid_2_price    double precision,
    ask_2_price    double precision,
    bid_2_quantity double precision,
    ask_2_quantity double precision,
    bid_3_price    double precision,
    ask_3_price    double precision,
    bid_3_quantity double precision,
    ask_3_quantity double precision,
    bid_4_price    double precision,
    ask_4_price    double precision,
    bid_4_quantity double precision,
    ask_4_quantity double precision,
    bid_5_price    double precision,
    ask_5_price    double precision,
    bid_5_quantity double precision,
    ask_5_quantity double precision
);
```

and the following composite index:

```
create index market_quotes_instrument_exchange_time_idx
    on market_quotes (instrument asc, exchange asc, time desc);
```

When I run the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select * from market_quotes where instrument='BTC/USD' and exchange='gdax' and time between '2020-06-02 00:00:00' and '2020-06-03 00:00:00'
```

It takes almost 2 minutes to return 500k rows:

```
Index Scan using _hyper_1_1_chunk_market_quotes_instrument_exchange_time_idx on _hyper_1_1_chunk  (cost=0.70..1353661.85 rows=1274806 width=183) (actual time=5.165..99990.424 rows=952931 loops=1)
"  Index Cond: (((instrument)::text = 'BTC/USD'::text) AND ((exchange)::text = 'gdax'::text) AND (""time"" >= '2020-06-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (""time"" <= '2020-06-02 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
Planning Time: 11.389 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 2
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 0.404 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.000 ms, Emission 0.000 ms, Total 0.404 ms"
Execution Time: 100121.392 ms
```

And when I run the query below:

```
select * from market_quotes where instrument='BTC/USD' and exchange='gdax' and time between '2020-06-02 00:00:00' and '2020-06-03 00:00:00'
```

This ran for >40 mins and crashed.

What can I do to speed the queries up? I often do 1 day queries - would it help if I added another column corresponding to the day of the week and indexed on that as well?

Should I be querying with a subset of rows each time instead and piecing the information together? (i.e. 10000 rows at a time)

Comment: It sounds like tool you are using for querying is getting out of memory, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you using timescaledb for this table, or is it merely installed but unused?

Comment: What crashes, the server or the client?

Comment: @HHH can you report how does it crash? What do you have in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to see the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query after setting `track_io_timing` to `on`.

But if you are desperate to speed up an index range scan, the best you can do is to cluster the table:

```
CLUSTER market_quotes USING market_quotes_instrument_exchange_time_idx;
```

This will rewrite the table and block any concurrent access.

Another approach would be to use a pre-aggregated materialized view, if you can live with slightly stale data.